# What is the strongest result that has subsequently been shown to just be a statistical glitch?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

While reading up on the $g-2$ result, I noticed that the authors stopped short of announcing a definitive result because they only had 4.2 sigma of confidence rather than the 5 that is the standard for confirmation. That got me thinking: Has anyone ever published results anything close to 5 sigma and then had it turn out to be a statistical glitch? (As opposed to for example a systemic error in construction or execution of the experiment.)

---

Edit:

I ran into a [mention of a 3.9 sigma result at the LHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/750_GeV_diphoton_excess) that turned out to be a statistical glitch

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of unexplained >5-sigma results out there, and the only way establish that one of them was a statistical glitch would be to prove that it had no systematic errors. This is impossible. There is a well-known aphorism that "[all models are wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong)", and all real measurements have inherent systematic errors. We can work hard to keep their effects small, but they can never be eliminated.  When a 5-sigma result is reported that later goes away without explanation, it is always far more likely that it was an unknown systematic effect than a statistical fluctuation.

One can, however, make a statistical argument that 5-sigma statistical glitches have been published.  [Several million scientific articles appear every year](http://blog.cdnsciencepub.com/21st-century-science-overload/) and the total number of scientific papers ever published is probably of order $10^8$. Not all scientific papers have experimental results, of course, but many report more than one result, so $10^8$ is a conservative guesstimate for a lower bound on the total number of published scientific measurements.  Given that the (2-sided) probability of a 5-sigma fluctuation is about one in two million, one would expect quite a few 5-sigma statistical fluctuations to have appeared in the scientific literature. It is just impossible to distinguish them from the more common 5-sigma unknown systematic errors.

Comment: An interesting point (thought I was actually more interested in examples). Though that also moots another question: have there been cases where the result was spurious due to a systematic bias where the cause of that bias was more interesting than the original result? -- "The results where effected by *what*?! Cool!"

Comment: It depends how you define "systematic bias", but I believe examples include the [discovery of the Cosmic Microwave Backgound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discovery_of_cosmic_microwave_background_radiation) and the resolution of the [Solar Neutrino Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino_problem) via neutrino oscillations.  Charm production was - in hindsight - [obvious in Drell-Yan experiments](https://www.phy.anl.gov/ectdrell-yan/1stDAY/Trento_DY_Peng.pdf) several years before it was discovered in 1974.